# Unable to find or install amazon-linux-extras

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install nginx on AWS EC2 instance. As this is done using amazon-linux-extras as per AWS documentation, I tried that. But I am unable to find the package or install it using yum install(it says that the package is already available but I am unable to find it using 'which'.

Below is the terminal output. Please help.

```
[arjun@ip-172-31-32-27 ~]$ which amazon-linux-extras

/usr/bin/which: no amazon-linux-extras in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/arjun/.local/bin:/home/arjun/bin)

[arjun@ip-172-31-32-27 ~]$ sudo yum -y install amazon-linux-extras

[sudo] password for arjun:

Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                               | 2.4 kB  00:00:00

Package amazon-linux-extras-1.6.9-1.amzn2.noarch already installed and latest version

Nothing to do
```

Comment: Found the file in default python2.7 of my AWS Linux 2 instance. But I am still unable to resolve the issue. Used 'find' command and found amazon_linux_extras here:  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazon_linux_extras

Comment: Please note `amazon-linux-extras` has been removed in release 2022 [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2022/release-notes/removed-packages-al2022.html)

Comment: @RichardTylerMiles - where is it documented that `amazon-linux-extras` has been removed? I'm having an issue where I'm trying to use the utility but it hangs silently when trying to install docker. However, a recent support post (01/25/2023) says to use it to upgrade the linux kernel [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-linux-2-kernel-upgrade/)

Comment: The disconnect is that Amazon Linux 2022 is the successor of Amazon Linux 2. [Full Changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2022/release-notes/compare-packages.html). Note al2 uses RHEL while al2022 is a Fedora spin off.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

> `amazon-linux-extras enable nginx`

EDIT: This answer was valid in 2019. It looks like extras was removed as of Dec 2022.

Comment: It says that... -bash: amazon-linux-extras: command not found

Comment: Are using Amazon Linux 2 AMI or just Amazon Linux AMI? You can check with `cat /etc/system-release`

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 AMI. I found a workaround to install nginx though: Using epel-release, that worked fine without the use of amazon-linux-extras...

Answer (score 0):

So Nginx is preinstalled in [Amazon Linux 2022](https://repost.aws/questions/QUF2TcvV2tR_qvd3gjDktxcA/in-place-upgrade-from-amazon-linux-2-to-al-2022), so really, you should upgrade the distribution you are using (Amazon Linux 2).

Generally, if you need to install on Amazon Linux 2 you should build from source. The code below is generally the method today, but it is typical to add/want extra modules which may modify the flags for `./auto/configure`, for example. More information on how to build Nginx's repo into its executable can be found on its online documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html.

```
git clone --quiet https://github.com/nginx/nginx.git

cd nginx || exit

./auto/configure --with-http_ssl_module --user=www-data --group=www-data

make

make install

nginx -t
```